How to build a good data structure for a react state, that allows me to easily update deeply nested array of objects?
I am trying to implement a property (real estate) chain
Each chain item should know which chain item is above/below it
A chain item can have its own sub-chain, and this in turn applies to its sub-chain items as well and so on
Visually like this
[
{
id: 1,
belowId:0
},
{
id: 0,
belowId:2,
aboveId:1,
subChain: [{ id:3, subChain: [{ id:4}] }]
},
{
id: 2,
aboveId:0
}
]

I tried this above structure but I started getting confused how to update nested items in state and ui

What are you struggling with at the moment with your update logic, and how are you trying to update? Do you want to update a certain property given its id?

you prefer a manual approach or just looking for a library?

I prefer a manual approach and struggling to find the right array/object to update.

You'll probably want to store and access all items by id. The subChain arrays should not contain object references but just ids. This means you won't have to traverse nested objects (or even search through them) to update anything; although you'll have to look up the structure when consuming the tree.

Can you please answer with an example that would be helpful for me

@Raffi what are the operations you need to support on your data structure? btw. seems what you're looking for is some combination of what is usually called a "linked list" and a "tree".

@mb21 I want to be able to add items on the same level as the root item either above or below and keep track of items above/below ids “at least”, also I want to add sub-items to each and so on. also later on i want to be able to delete a node and its children. After explaining do you still think it should be a linked list?

Also @mb21 items in a chain are not limited to one above or one below it can have as many items above/below

Okay, so what particular problem did you run in? What update operation "confused" you? Perhaps read https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure ?

@mb21 I think most probably what confused me is how to update the state properly and keep track of ids, while still be able to show everything in the UI properly.
I have answered my own question with the solution that I ended up with, it would be great if you can evaluate the solution. thanks!

What does this have to do with functional programming?

@JaredSmith While React is not strictly functional but it incorporates functional programming principles

@Raffi I'm well aware of that, the name React even comes from Functional Reactive Programming. But what does this question have to do with functional programming?

@JaredSmith It asks to design a data structure for a react state - a purely functional data structure since react states are immutable.

As no one has answered my question, maybe I wasn't clear enough too to be fair. I will answer it here so that if someone stumbles on a similar problem.
So the main idea is that you want to flatten the array and make sure that subChain only consist of ids not references.
Here is how the ChainItem look like (state structure)
type ChainItem = {
    id: string;
    root: boolean;
    subChain: string[];
    aboveId?: string;
    belowId?: string;
    parentId?: string;
};

I create an item with this utility method
const createItem = (id: number, root: boolean = false): ChainItem => {
    return { id: `${id}`, root, aboveId: null, belowId: null, parentId: null, subChain: [] };
};

How it looks in the UI
interface ChainTreeItem extends Omit<ChainItem, "subChain"> {
    subChain: ChainTreeItem[];
}

I build the UI tree like this
const buildTree = (chain: ChainItem[], id: string) => {
    const itemMap = new Map(chain.map(item => [item.id, item]));
    const build = (id: string): ChainTreeItem | null => {
        const item = itemMap.get(id);
        if (!item) return null;

        return {
            ...item,
            subChain: item.subChain.map(subId => build(subId))
        };
    };

    return build(id);
};

React state
const [chain, setChain] = useState<ChainItem[]>([createItem(0, true)]);
const chainTree: ChainTreeItem[] = useMemo(() => {
    return chain.filter(property => property.root).map(property => buildTree(chain, property.id));
}, [chain]);

Create a sibling
const addSibling = useCallback((id: string, position: "above" | "below") => {
        const isAddAbove = position === "above";
        setChain(prev => {
            let parent: PropertyItem | null = null;
            const newItem = createItem(prev.length);
            let updated = prev.map(item => {
                if (item.id === id) {
                    parent = prev.find(itm => itm.id === item.parentId);
                    if (isAddAbove) {
                        newItem.belowId = item.id;
                        return { ...item, aboveId: newItem.id };
                    } else {
                        newItem.aboveId = item.id;
                        return { ...item, belowId: newItem.id };
                    }
                }
                return item;
            });
            if (parent) {
                newItem.parentId = parent.id;
                updated = updated.map(item => {
                    if (item.id === parent.id) {
                        return {
                            ...item,
                            subChain: isAddAbove ? [newItem.id, ...item.subChain] : [...item.subChain, newItem.id]
                        };
                    }
                    return item;
                });
            } else {
                newItem.root = true;
            }
            return isAddAbove ? [newItem, ...updated] : [...updated, newItem];
        });
    }, []);

Create a sub chain
 const addRight = useCallback((id: string) => {
        setChain(prev => {
            const newItem = createItem(prev.length);
            const updated = prev.map(item => {
                if (item.id === id) {
                    newItem.parentId = item.id;
                    return { ...item, subChain: [...item.subChain, newItem.id] };
                }
                return item;
            });
            return [...updated, newItem];
        });
    }, []);


You should look into a state management library like Redux. With Redux you'll have a global state store that all of your components can pull from.

But I don’t need global access, I want to know how I can update a specific chain with new property items within it or add new nested subChain

Listing below the two key characteristics of the requirements:
a. Each chain item should know which chain item is above/below it
b. A chain item can have its own sub-chain, and this in turn applies to its sub-chain items as well and so on.
To avoid mutation of objects in React, the code needs to work as below:
a. For a change in any object in a sub-chain, the whole containing object must be rebuilt. However, the objects nested inside the changed object will be unaffected. Similarly, the other containing objects if any in the same sub-chain will also be unaffected. This point is further explained below with an example.
Example
subChain: [{ id:3, subChain: [{ id:4, subChain : [{ id: 5 }]}]}, {id : 6}]

When the object { id:4, subChain : [{ id: 5 }]} changes, then the whole containing object { id:3, subChain: [{ id:4, subChain : [{ id: 5 }]}]} must be rebuilt. However the nested object in the changed object { id: 5 } will remain unaffected. Similarly the other containing in the same sub-chain object{id : 6} will also be unaffected.
As the whole containing object in a sub-chain is always changed here, this change will cascade to the main-chain. Point b states the same.
b. For a change in any object either in the main chain or in a sub-chain , the whole main chain needs to be rebuilt.
case 1 : a change in a sub-chain as explained in point a.
For a change in the object { id:4, subChain : [{ id: 5 }]}, the object { id : 0, … } must be rebuilt since a containing object in its sub-chain has been changed. The newly rebuilt object will also call for re-building the objects above and below which will result a whole rebuilding process for the entire main chain.
 {
      id: 1,
      belowId: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 0,
      belowId: 2,
      aboveId: 1,
      subChain: { id: 3, subChain: { id: 4, subChain: { id: 5 } } },
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      aboveId: 0,
    },

case 2 : a change in the main-chain
When the object { id : 0, …} changes, this is a direct change in the object which is separate from the changes in its sub-chain. let us say, its id is changing from 0 to 100. Therefore the same object must be newly built. Now the objects above and below will also be affected by this change. And it will call for the whole main-chain to be rebuilt. However the sub-chains in all objects in the main chain will remain unaffected.
